# „Mandaliet“ in den Carmina Burana

Tags: lyrics, middle-high-german

In den *Carmina Burana* gibt es die Stelle:

> Mandaliet, mandaliet,
>
> min geselle
>
> chumet niet.

wobei *mandaliet* manchmal auch als zwei Wörter geschrieben wurde.

Ich habe sowohl gehört, dass das Wort nichts bedeutet (so wie lalala), als auch, dass *liet* Lied bedeutet, mit verschiedenen unplausiblen Vorschlägen für *manda*.

Weiß hier jemand mehr darüber?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ich habe die Carmina Burana schon mehrmals gesungen. Uns wurde damals bei einer der Proben von einem Experten erklärt, dass die »Manda« die »Männer« sind (ist auch heute noch in Tirol so), und dass die »Liet« »Leute« sind.

Die »Mandaliet« sind also »Männerleute«, also eine Gruppe von Männern. Der Satz »Mandaliet, Manda Liet, min geselle chumet niet« heißt also wörtlich:

> Männerleute, Männer, Leute! Mein Freund kommt nicht.

Die Aussage, dass der Freund nicht kommt, wird also an eine Gruppe von Männern gerichtet

Comment: Sehr schöne, einfache und plausible Erklärung. Damit ergibt auch das Lied sehr viel Sinn: In den Strophen singt der schmachtende Liebhaber auf Latein, und im Refrain beschwert sich die Geliebte auf Deutsch ganz prosaisch, dass er so lang auf sich warten lässt. (Typisch Mannsvolk!)

Comment: Ich habe gelernt, dass "chumet niet" nicht "kommt nicht" bedeutet, sondern in diesem Zusammenhang "klagt nicht" (nämlich dass die Jungfernschaft verloren geht). Wortzusammenhang mit "Kummer" und rheinisch "kömen".

Comment: Das liest sich zwar sehr plausibel, wird aber von Wackernagels Mittelhochdeutschem Wörterbuch und auch dem von Benecke, Müller, Zarncke widersprochen - dort gibt es Einträge **manda-liet** *stn. ( freuden-, tanzlied.)*  und auch einen Querverweis auf die Carmina Burana

Comment: @MargoschaIve: Die Carmina Burana ("Lieder aus Beuern") wurden im Mittelalter in Beuern in ein von den Benediktinern betriebenen Kloster eingelagert und vermutlich auch in der Nähe dieses Ortes geschrieben. Das Kloster heißt heute Benediktbeuern und liegt ziemlich genau in der Mitte der Verbindungslinie zwischen München und Innsbruck, rund 10 km von Bad Tölz entfernt, im Süden Bayerns, nahe der Grenze zu Tirol. Warum hätte man dort, in Südbayern, rund 30 km von Tirol entfernt, Rheinisch sprechen sollen? Da scheinen mir die Tiroler *Manda* doch naheliegender zu sein.

Comment: @tofro: Gibt es dazu auch Quellen im Internet? Ich glaube dir zwar, weil die Tiroler *Manda* zwar plausibel, aber auch nicht mehr als eben nur plausibel sind. Wenn du etwas fundierteres hast, würde ich das gerne mal nachlesen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast z.B. da: https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=Lexer&lemid=LM00272#0 - Gibt aber nicht viel her.

Comment: Leider ist deine Antwort auch schon auf anderen Seiten verlinkt, weil sie so naheliegend ist: https://www.carminaburanalive.nl/nieuws/57-manda-liet

Comment: @tofro: Der Eintrag gibt tatsächlich nicht viel her. Vor allem: Was soll denn *»Tanzlied, Tanzlied, mein Freund kommt nicht«* bedeuten? Das Lied Nr. 18 *Circa mea pectora,* in dem die Stelle vorkommt, ist ein Liebeslied bei dem es in der letzen Strophe um die Befreiung aus den Fesseln der Jungfräulichkeit geht. Es steht auch genau an der Stelle im Abschnitt *Cour d'amours* (Lieder 15 bis 23) wo die Texte von *romantisch* zu *eindeutig zweideutig* übergehen. Die Tanzlieder befinden sich weit davor, im Abschnitt "Uf dem Anger" (Lieder 6 bis 10). (Dazwischen sind 4 Sauflieder)

Comment: Die Online-Ausgabe gibt zugegeben nicht viel her. Bloß: Der Wackernagel ist eins der drei Standardwerke des Mittelhochdeutschen. Auf den würde ich schon vertrauen. Auf der anderen Seite: Was ist an  "Männers, Männers, mein Freund kommt nicht" soviel besser?

Comment: @tofro: Das ist eine Anrede (Vokativ), vergleichbar mit „Jungs, mein Freund kommt nicht“ oder „Ladies and gentlemen, my friend is not comming“. Ich halte das schon für erheblich schlüssiger als „Tanzlied, mein Freund kommt nicht“.

Answer (score 5):

"Mandaliet, mandaliet, min geselle chumet niet."
"Hurray, hurray, my lover is coming with promptness."

According to a medieval to modern German language dictionary, covering the XIIth to XIVth century period :
Manda = a verb of enthusiasm. Liet = Lied (song). Niet = mit promptheit.

A dictionary (I do not have the reference any more) that I consulted 20 years ago at McGill University, when I was in a choir and amazed by the incomplete or inappropriate translation of the Carmina Burana according to the situation in the cantata : happy moments for youth in summer time.
Joyful chorus.

P.-S. : I finally found the reference.
« Mittelhochdeutsches Handwörterbuch » from Matthias Ritter von Lexer.
Manda-liet = Tanzlied :   http://woerterbuchnetz.de/Lexer/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=Lexer&mode=Volltextsuche&lemid=LM00272#XLM00272

Answer (score 3):

The word "manda" actually exists still today in German. You can find it still spoken in South Tyrolia. It means "men".

Also, in Bavaria the word "mannerleut" oder stärker eingefärbt "mannaleit" for men, also resembles "manda liet".

Answer (score 2):

In the following, I will refer what I, as a layman, have drawn from Olive Sayce (1967), "*Carmina Burana* 180 and the *mandaliet* refrain", in: *Oxford German Studies*, vol. 2, p. 1-12.

The refrain in question, from *Carmina Burana* 180, reads:

> Manda liet manda liet min geselle chǒmet niet.

It is attached to a Latin poem, which shares the love letter theme with the preceding German one, 179a, *Einen brief ich sande / einer vrowen gůt.* However, the content of the German refrain of 180 has nothing to do with the Latin poem and "it can only have been fortuitously attached to it" (Sayce; she also notes that the surrounding poems all have refrains, which might have been a reason for attaching one to 180).

The *mandaliet* refrain resembles that of 180a:

> Ich sage dir ih sage dir min geselle chum mit mir.

Now, with regard to the meaning of the mystery word *mandaliet*, Sayce points out that although *menden* "rejoice" did exist (see [AWB](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemma=menden)), it was archaic at the time, and no compounds with *manda-* are attested.

If the word *mandaliet* doesn't exist, what could it mean? Well, nothing, says Sayce:

> It is certainly an invented nonce-word of the type very common in refrains. It is simply there to provide (a) the requisite number of beats demanded by the metre, (b) the rhyme. That the second element should take the form of a real word for the sake of the rhyme, though meaningless in the context in which it occurs, is also a device of common occurrence.

Sayce also argues that the refrain was taken from a dance song (which I find quite plausible; after the solo part, the crowd would join in on the *mandaliets*). So although Wackernagel's interpretation of *mandaliet* as "dance-song" (recorded by [Lexer](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/Lexer?lemid=M00272)) may have been wrong on a linguistic level, he might have been right about what the refrain is conveying.

If you want to check out the manuscript of *Carmina Burana* 180, take a look at [MDZ](https://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/0008/bsb00085130/images/index.html?id=00085130&seite=145), or go [here](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/Chronologia/Lspost13/CarminaBurana/bur_cam6.html#180) for a transcription. You may also enjoy listening to the song "Mandaliet" by the band *Dunkelschön*, from their album [Katharsis](https://www.dunkelschoen-musik.de/home.html/audio/katharsis/) (2009).

Answer (score -2):

We once sang the lyrics in the boy scouts and I was told that "Manda liet" means Great sorrow. The modern German word for sorrow is Leid. I can see how this is related to Liet. So that would be Liet=Leid=Sorrow. However, there is no modern german word that closely resembles manda. Maybe it could be related to Menge (amount, lot). In any case Great sorrow makes sence in the context.

Comment: A modern german word that very, very closely resembles manda is »Manda«. It is exactly the Tyrolan dialect word for »Männer« (men). The Monastery Benediktbeuern, where the Carmina Burana (the textbook, written many centuries ago) was found, is only 15 km away from the border to the Tyrol. See more here: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/22144/1487

Answer (score -3):

My German professor in college speculated that "manda liet" was an archaic expression that, in modern German, could be "man da liegt" or "man liegt da" ("one lies there (or here)"). Man da liegt; mein Freund kommt nicht.

Comment: 1.) Das ergibt überhaupt keinen Sinn. 2.) Warum antwortest du in einem Deutsch-Forum, in dem jemand auf Deutsch eine Frage zu einem deutschen Text stellt, in einer Fremdsprache?